# How to parse parameters of type Array in Rust FFi

Tags: node.js, rust, ffi

I have an export function, how to parse the parameters of the array type in the parameter；

I don’t know if my writing is correct；

```
use safer_ffi::{prelude::*};

#[derive_ReprC]
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct FfiArray<'a> {
    pub data: *const f64,
    pub len: usize,
    _marker: std::marker::PhantomData<&'a [f64]>,
}

#[ffi_export]
pub fn my_push(array: FfiArray) {
    // let slice = std::slice::from_raw_parts(array.data, array.len);
    println!("my_push: {array:?}");
}
```

test.mjs

```
import ffi from "ffi-napi";
import ref from "ref-napi";
import ref_struct from "ref-struct-di";
import ref_array from "ref-array-di";

const StructType = ref_struct(ref);
const ArrayType = ref_array(ref);

const DoubleArray = ArrayType(ref.types.double);

const libm = ffi.Library("./target/release/wave_from_tools.dll", {
  my_push: ["void", [DoubleArray]]
});

libm.my_push(new DoubleArray([1.2, 2.2]));
```

Parsing failed：my_push: FfiArray { data: 0x3ff3333333333333, len: 4612136378390124954, _marker: PhantomData<&[f64]> }

Can be correctly output array type：

```
[1,2,3,4] or [{ idx: 2, name: "test_name" }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#[ffi_export]
pub fn my_push<'xs>(array: c_slice::Ref<'xs, i32>) {
  // let p = array.as_slice().iter().max();
  println!("p: {array:?}"); // p: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
}
```

test.mjs

```
const ArrayInt32List = StructType({
  ptr: Int32ArrayType,
  len: ref.types.int,
});
const libm = ffi.Library("./target/release/wave_from_tools.dll", {
  my_push: ["void", [ArrayInt32List]]
});

const tmpList = new Int32ArrayType([1,2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
const int32List = new ArrayInt32List({
  ptr: tmpList,
  len: tmpList.length,
});
libm.my_push(int32List);
```

Because passing pointers and sizes.
https://github.com/getditto/safer_ffi/blob/master/src/slice.rs#L282